# Passing python variable to powershell script

Tags: python, powershell

I have the following small powershell script which creates a local account.

**create_new_user.ps1** :

```
param([string]$username)

New-LocalUser -Name $username -Description "Test account" -NoPassword
```

I would like to pass $username variable from python script as follows;

**script.py** :

```
import subprocess, sys

def runscript():

    username = "testaccount"
    p = subprocess.Popen(['powershell',"-ExecutionPolicy","Unrestricted", './create_new_user.ps1', username], 
            stdout=sys.stdout)

    p.communicate()

runscript()
```

When i run the script.py, it asks me to input Name for the account and then it creates the account but it  does not take the variable from script.py

How can i solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `... "-File", './create_new_user.ps1', '-username:', username`

Comment: Thanks for your response but it did not solve the issue.

`p = subprocess.Popen(['powershell',"-ExecutionPolicy","Unrestricted", "-File", './create_new_user.ps1', '-username:', username]`